# Can't resolve redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm trying to use react-redux but keep getting this error whenever I import anything from redux or react-redux:

```
./node_modules/react-redux/es/index.js
Module not found: Can't resolve '/Users/danielcraig/Documents/ill/ill/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js' in '/Users/danielcraig/Documents/ill/ill'
```

where the directory of my project is 'ill'.

Any idea on how to resolve?

Comment: `npm i react-redux --save`

Comment: ./src/index.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'redux' in '/Users/danielcraig/Documents/ill/ill/src'

Answer (score 0):

You need to install redux in order to be able to load react-redux

```
npm install --save redux react-redux
```